# Big static HTML and jQuery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm learning jQuery, as you can see from my last questions. Now I try to make a really big static html a bit more navigable.

A part of the html:

```
<a class="entryheader">...</a><br /><br />
<div class="entrycontent">...<br />
<p class="entryfoot">...</p>

<a class="entryheader">...</a><br /><br />
<div class="entrycontent">...<br />
<p class="entryfoot">...</p>
```

My JS:

```
$("a.entryheader").click(function(){
 alert("clicked");
 $(this).next("div.entrycontent").show();
});
```

Entrycontent is hidden by default and should only be visible if the user clicks on entryheader.

If I click on entryheader I get the messagebox, but entrycontent stays invisible.

I tried different approaches for $(this).next but none worked.

Probably I lack the understanding of the DOM model. What tools and documentations do you recommend?

Comment: `console.log();` is great for figuring out what is wrong. For example: `console.log( $(this).next() );` inside your click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `next()` looks for the next element in the html. In your case you are using a bunch of `BR` tags as  separators, so `next()` will be a `BR`

Best solution is use the code you have and remove the `BR` tags and use CSS to apply margin for separation.

If you keep the `BR` tags, you could use `index()` method

```
$("a.entryheader").click(function(){
     var index=$("a.entryheader").index(this)
     $("div.entrycontent").eq(index).show();
});
```

**DEMO using index**  http://jsfiddle.net/fUeZE/

Comment: Would something like that work for all entrycontent blocks which are visible but don't match the index? $("div.entrycontent").neq(index).hide();

Comment: there is no `neq()` method but due to jQuery chaining this is simple  `$("div.entrycontent").hide().eq(index).show();`

Comment: Is it better to use chaining or something like if($('div.entrycontent').is(':visible') )... ?

Comment: the chain only searches the DOM once. Your `if` will be more code also

Comment: Tyvm. One additional question:
$("a.entryheader").click(function(){
$(".entryconent").hide();
var index=$("a.entryheader").index(this)
$("div.entrycontent").eq(index).slideToggle(300);
});
Works. But how can I use slideToggle instead of hide?

Comment: Filter out the visible ones in one line  can use `.is(':visible')`, then the `eq()` in another line

Answer (score 2):

The other way of achieving what you want with your code is using jQuery's `nextAll()` traversal method to match all of the next elements with a class of `.entrycontent` but then filtering to just the first found like so.

```
$("a.entryheader").click(function(){ 
    $(this).nextAll('div.entrycontent').first().show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qhP2s/)

More info on [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).next('div.entrycontent')` won't select anything in your case since the next sibling after the anchor tag is the `<br />` tag.  I would remove the `<br />` tags and add some margin-bottom to the anchor tag to create the same affect and then your `.next` code above will work.

Comment: This: $(this).next().next().next("div.entrycontent").show(); will work but it's stupid... I will try again the index method as used in my toc solution (former question)

Comment: I agree that is stupid and that's not the solution proposed. If you remove the extra `<br />` HTML tags then your original code will work and will be faster than selecting all the siblings like using `nextAll` or using indices.